# How to CRUD a Generic Class with Generic List in NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Let's say I have a class like this

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public List<Work> Employments { get; set; }
}

public class Work
{
    public string Employer { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

My controller have both HttpGet and httpPost for Edit

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var _item = new Person()
    {
        Id = id,
        Name = "Bob",
        BirthDate = new DateTime(1970, 3, 4),
        Employments = new List<Work>()
        {
            new Work(){ Employer="Microsoft", Salary=5000, StartDate= new DateTime(1998, 1, 1), EndDate=new DateTime(2005, 12, 31)},
            new Work(){ Employer="Google", Salary=6000, StartDate= new DateTime(2006, 1, 1), EndDate=new DateTime(2013, 12, 31)},
            new Work(){ Employer="Spotify", Salary=10000, StartDate= new DateTime(2014, 1, 1)}
        }
    };
    return View(_item);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(Person _item)
{
    return View(_item);
}
```

and my Edit.csthml looks like

```
@Model  Person

<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="string" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BirthDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="date" asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <GRID>
        table with the rows of Work
    </GRID>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

I don't know how to get the Grid part, all example I see are the grid standalone or have own AJAX request, not part of the other properties.

In old asp.net WebForms you could have it in one update.

So how do you do things like this in .NET Core?

The question is NOT part of the update in database, I use Dapper and stored procedures, not EF Core...

The question is how to retrieve the edited data to my generic class before DB-update...

Comment: why do you need a grid? you can retrieve the data to a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you want to update person and corresponding work data on the edit
>   view?

First of all, **there is no Grid tag in core**, you can use the original `table tag` to display the table.

And you also need to put the `Id` key field of the Person class into the form, and use the `hidden` control to hide it to ensure that the value of the Id field can also be passed.

To ensure that all updated data can be passed to the controller, you need to add the **name** attribute to the control corresponding to the `work` class and ensure that they are in the form of **Employments[index].FieldName**.

More details, please refer to the following example:

```
@model Person
@{
    var i = 0;
}
<form asp-action="Edit">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="BirthDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="date" asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Employer</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>StartDate</th>
                <th>EndDate</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Employments)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" asp-for="@item.Employer" name="Employments[@i].Employer" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.Employer" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" asp-for="@item.Salary" name="Employments[@i].Salary" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.Salary" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" asp-for="@item.StartDate" name="Employments[@i].StartDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.StartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" asp-for="@item.EndDate" name="Employments[@i].EndDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.EndDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                i++;
            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: YES! Thanks, that was exact what  was looking for!